# Upload file using HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I've copied the following code from [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/multipart-http-requests), the one thing that I have replaced is using Map instead of the split as shown in commented lines below, my code start right after it.

This code works perfectly all the time except with one device where it fails sometimes, the code seems to be stuck inside this block, I didn't get any exception btw, it just stuck there.

```
while (iter.hasNext()) {
....
}
```

**Update**
           I don't have physical access to the phone so I printed a log for each line, even the exception, and I see that the code is stuck in the loop mentioned above, and also note that the http parameters are fixed to 4.

I put a Log inside it and I see that it reached that block and finished all the params and then didn't get out of it, what am I doing here?

```
    public ResponseObject multipartRequest(String urlTo, String post, Map httpPara, String filepath, String filefield) throws ParseException, IOException {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        int ResponseCode; 

        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary =  "*****"+Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis())+"*****";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";

        String result = "";

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

        String[] q = filepath.split("/");
        int idx = q.length - 1;

        try { 
                File file = new File(filepath);
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                URL url = new URL(urlTo);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setUseCaches(false);

                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android Multipart HTTP Client 1.0");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);
                Log.i(Commons.TAG, "filepath " + getMimeType(filepath) );

                outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + filefield + "\"; filename=\"" + q[idx] +"\"" + lineEnd);
               // outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: video/mp4" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + getMimeType(filepath) + lineEnd);

                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                while(bytesRead > 0) {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // Upload POST Data
//                String[] posts = post.split("&");
//                int max = posts.length;
//                for(int i=0; i<max;i++) {
//                        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
//                        String[] kv = posts[i].split("=");
//                        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + kv[0] + "\"" + lineEnd);
//                        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain"+lineEnd);
//                        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
//                        outputStream.writeBytes(kv[1]);
//                        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
//                }
//                
                Iterator iter = httpPara.entrySet().iterator();

                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry para = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
                     outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                     outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + para.getKey().toString() + "\"" + lineEnd);
                     outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain"+lineEnd);
                     outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                     outputStream.writeBytes(para.getValue().toString());
                     outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                }
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

                ResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode(); 
                inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                result = this.convertStreamToString(inputStream);

                fileInputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();


                return new ResponseObject(ResponseCode, result);
        } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("MultipartRequest","Multipart Form Upload Error");

                e.printStackTrace();

                return null;
        }
}
```

Comment: is there any stacktrace?

Comment: I don't see anything, no exception no error.

Comment: I don't have physical access to this phone to be honest, so I had to write debug log and asked the user to send me the file. But I wrote debug for every single step and I see that it stuck in the loop, and it's not happening all the time